# How to create tests?

Tags: testing, tdd

Sorry for the generic question, but is a doubt about the TDD.
The TDD says first a create test case and after this write the code. But I have a difficult to follow this steps. I mean for create a code from scratch, firstly I do an outline of how will the relationship of objects, and after this in theory I start with the test, but for me is a little difficult to abstract everything I need to write in test.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what you do for create test first? You make a list of all behavior you will test before really start to write test, or something else?

Comment: Try to practice TDD on something smaller. Once you feel comfortable, move to a bigger project. Take a look at Roy Osherove's kata here: http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/   Here's an example walk-through http://technologyconversations.com/2013/12/20/test-driven-development-tdd-example-walkthrough/

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will read the links.

Comment: Personally I would suggest not even doing the outline of the relationship of objects. Just start with a very basic thing of what you have to implement. Extend the data model you are using not before you need to extend it. For example I started some applications that implement a network service just by a test that it accepts a network connection on the right port. Then I write the smallest possible implementation that accepts a connection. Then I write the next test, for example that there should be sent out a greeting on the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking too large.  When you talk about an outline and multiple objects, you're thinking about the big picture, and unit testing - the kind of testing we typically talk about when we talk about TDD - unit testing is about testing tiny elements of functionality.  Not even full classes, just individual methods of those classes.  And you're not anticipating and writing a set of tests before writing your code - you're writing one.  One tiny test, then write the code you need to get that test to pass.  Then clean up as needed, then iterate again with the next tiny bit of functionality.

You will have an idea of the objects you'll be writing and an idea of their relationships, but just a hazy one, and you don't need to refine that beforehand.  Instead, you refine it as you go, test by test, method by method.  And when you recognize a way to improve your design - the concrete already-written classes you've developed so far - you make that improvement, so your design, instead of being painstakingly figured out ahead of time, without context of classes and tests, instead, your design emerges, a bit at a time, alongside your code and your tests, through your code and your tests.

Start with a single test.  You'll need to create a class to pass that test, and you'll need to add a method to that class.  When you're happy with the state of that single method of that single class, then figure out what the next bit of functionality should be, and write a test for it.

That's TDD.  It takes practice and discipline, but it's a great way to write great code.  Good luck!